# How to identify a bootstrap custom-control-input of type checkbox through Selenium

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm writing a web-app with java. I'm testing all the html pages with selenium-java but I've a problem with the [custom forms](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_forms_custom.asp) that comes from bootstrap 4

Going in deep, I've the following code

```
<input class="custom-control-input"
       type="checkbox"
       id="registerForm:termsCheckbox"
       border-color:lime" required="true"/>
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="registerForm:termsCheckbox">
     I agree to <a href="terms.html" 
          style="text-decoration:underline; color:lime">terms and conditions
                </a>
  </label>
```

With this code, Even though the checkbox is visibile, apparently bootstrap  hides the  control. And with Selenium I don't know how to click on the checkbox.
Seems that the visible checkbox is an ::before or ::after.

How can I select with Selenium a bootstrap custom-control-input of type checkbox?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with executing javascript click.

Here is an example:

```
public void clickElementWithJS(By locator) {
    String jsClickCode = "arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true); arguments[0].click();";
    try {
        WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(locator);
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(jsClickCode, elementToClick);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Element could not be clicked.. "  + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To click the *checkbox* you need to click the label by either of the following locators, rather than click the checkbox itself.

The checkbox is configured to be transparent and behind the label by following css:

```
.custom-control-input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

- `CSS`:

  ```
  label[for='registerForm:termsCheckbox']
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  //label[@for='registerForm:termsCheckbox']
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Clicking on the label using your xpath will open the "terms and condition" page. Basically clicking on the label means click on the link. But I've tried to remove the link and yout approach works. But unfortunately in my case I can't remove that link

Comment: Is it an assumption or this happens when you use the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try sending the space key to the `input` element. For example:

`driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(Keys.SPACE)`